Session doesnt continue on other pages
Hello i have an issue within my .php website where i do login on this page:
<?php

include '../conn.php';
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {     //pokud post tak se joinu na server a vezmu si data z formu
    $username = $_POST['prihlas_jmeno'];
    $heslo = $_POST['heslo'];

$query = "SELECT id_osoba, username FROM osoba WHERE heslo=?";      //praprava rikazu 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $heslo);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {           //pokud prave jeden vysledek podle zadanych dat tak to hodim jako session promennou
        $_SESSION["uziv_jmen"] = $username;
        header("Location: https://project.skolakrizik.cz/~borysmandrovnyy/index.php");          //poslu se na index page
        } else {
         echo "Nastala chyba";          //pokud neco nepofachalo
        }
    
} else {
    echo "Invalid request method";          //pokus by to bylo poslanou jinou metodou než post
}                                                      
$stmt->close();         //zavřu statement
$conn->close();         //zavřu connection

?>


After sucesfully getting redirected onto my main page, where I do have
<?php
session_start();
?>

And after that i wanna redirect to page that i named my profile and it doesnt type out anything.
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="view" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Můj účet</title>
    <!-- DotGothic16 -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DotGothic16&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Monsterrat -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- ___ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mmMYaCCXDXD.css">
    
    <?php include 'conn.php';?>
    
</head>
<body>

<a href="../index.php">
    <p class="button">Zpět na hlavní stránku</p>
</a>
                                                        <!--
<div class="user-info-box">
    <h2>Vaše údaje:</h2>
        <p><strong>Username:</strong> user123</p>
        <p><strong>Name:</strong> John</p>
        <p><strong>Surname:</strong> Doe</p>
    </div>
                                                        -->

    <div class="user-info-box2">
        <h2>Vaše údaje:</h2>
            
        <?php
        //  $_SESSION["uziv_jmen"];

        //echo "<p><strong>" . "Username:" . "</strong>" . $_SESSION["uziv_jmen"] . "</p>"
        echo "<p><strong>" . "Uživatel:" . "</strong>" . $_SESSION["uziv_jmen"] . "</p>";

        //$sql = "SELECT jmeno,prijmeni FROM osoba WHERE username='$username'";
        //$result = $conn->query($sql);
        //$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        //echo "<h1>" . $row["jmeno"] . "</h1>";
        //echo "<h1>" . $row["prijmeni"] . "</h1>";
        ?> 
        </div>


<a href="../zmenaHesla/zHesla.php">
    <p class="button" id="zMENA">Změna hesla </p>
</a>

</body>
</html>

I tried googling, but the only thing i found was talking about oppening seession on every page before any html tags. I exptected to display a message saying its user name in the web that is supposed to dipaly ur profile info. With this php code:
echo "<p><strong>" . "Uživatel:" . "</strong>" . $_SESSION["uziv_jmen"] . "</p>";

I dont know if i need cookies or how to get it to work. Thank you for replies and your time trying to help.
Edit: i dont have much access to hosting service since its a school project.
and my database looks like this:
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Mon May 20 18:03:42 2024
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema borysmandrovnyy
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema borysmandrovnyy
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `borysmandrovnyy` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `borysmandrovnyy`.`osoba`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy`.`osoba` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy`.`osoba` (
  `id_osoba` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `jmeno` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `prijmeni` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `telefon` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `heslo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `vek` INT NOT NULL,
  `zeme` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `mesto` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `ulice` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cislo_popisne` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_osoba`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_osoba_UNIQUE` (`id_osoba` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `borysmandrovnyy`.`obrazek`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy`.`obrazek` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy`.`obrazek` (
  `idobrazek` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nazev` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cesta` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idobrazek`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idobrazek_UNIQUE` (`idobrazek` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `borysmandrovnyy`.`produkt`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy`.`produkt` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy`.`produkt` (
  `id_produkt` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nazev` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cena` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `kategorie` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `novinka` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `stav` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `akce` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `obrazek_idobrazek` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_produkt`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idprodukt_UNIQUE` (`id_produkt` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_produkt_obrazek1_idx` (`obrazek_idobrazek` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_produkt_obrazek1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`obrazek_idobrazek`)
    REFERENCES `borysmandrovnyy`.`obrazek` (`idobrazek`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `borysmandrovnyy`.`kosik`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy`.`kosik` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy`.`kosik` (
  `idkosik` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `osoba_id_osoba` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idkosik`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idkosik_UNIQUE` (`idkosik` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_kosik_osoba1_idx` (`osoba_id_osoba` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_kosik_osoba1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`osoba_id_osoba`)
    REFERENCES `borysmandrovnyy`.`osoba` (`id_osoba`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `borysmandrovnyy`.`kosik_polozky`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy`.`kosik_polozky` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `borysmandrovnyy`.`kosik_polozky` (
  `idkosik_polozky` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kosik_idkosik` INT NOT NULL,
  `produkt_id_produkt` INT NOT NULL,
  `pocet` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idkosik_polozky`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idkosik_polozky_UNIQUE` (`idkosik_polozky` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_kosik_polozky_kosik1_idx` (`kosik_idkosik` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_kosik_polozky_produkt1_idx` (`produkt_id_produkt` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_kosik_polozky_kosik1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`kosik_idkosik`)
    REFERENCES `borysmandrovnyy`.`kosik` (`idkosik`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_kosik_polozky_produkt1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`produkt_id_produkt`)
    REFERENCES `borysmandrovnyy`.`produkt` (`id_produkt`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

EDIT 2 - SOLUTION
Instead of just doing echo, I created this block:
        <?php
        session_start();
        
        if (isset($_SESSION["uziv_jmen"])) {
            echo "User ID: " . $_SESSION["uziv_jmen"];
        } else {
            echo "No user is logged in.";
        }
        ?>

I think it is becuase of how the server manages sessions, i guess? Cause starting it once doesnt do anything, but after starting it again in the code helped.

It's difficult to say what's going on. However, you can debug this situation. We assume that every time we do session_start(); that we're in the same session, and therefore $_SESSION["uziv_jmen"] should contain the user name. You can check if the session is still the same with echo session_id(); after session_start();. It should return the same id on all your pages.

Thank you I just found the problem. It is something probably with the hosting and how it manages sessions. Since after creating session_start two time instead only once worked.

"SELECT jmeno,prijmeni FROM osoba WHERE username='$username'" - please be warned that some of your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

@NicoHaase, thank you for your recommendation. I will try my best at sceuring my page. Have a nice rest of the day and thank you again.
